# Logstash conf file not parsing files according to the mentioned charset mentioned

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to parse certain files(.txt, .doc , .pdf etc).

This is my conf file .

input {

```
   stdin {
   codec => plain { 
    charset => "UTF-8" 
}
}
```

file {

```
path => ["/home/jk/Jk/doc/*"]
}

}


filter{

grok {

    match => ["message" ,"a-zA-Z0-9"]
}
}  

output {

file{
 path=>"/home/jk/Jk/jk6.txt"
}
```

}

The output i am getting is like this :

{"path":"/home/jk/Jk/doc/Jayakrishnan-Resume.docx","@timestamp":"2017-03-17T17:35:46.228Z","@version":"1","host":"Jk","message":["\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\v\u0000\u0000\u0000_rels/.rels\xAD\x92MK\u0003A\f\x86\xEF\xFD\u0015C\xEE\xDDl+\x88\xC8\xCE\xF6\\"Bo\\"\xF5\a\x84\x99\xEC\xEE\xD0\xCE\a3i\xAD\xFF\xDEA","\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\v\u0000\u0000\u0000_rels/.rels\xAD\x92MK\u0003A\f\x86\xEF\xFD\u0015C\xEE\xDDl+\x88\xC8\xCE\xF6\\"Bo\\"\xF5\a\x84\x99\xEC\xEE\xD0\xCE\a3i\xAD\xFF\xDEA"]}
{"path":"/home/jk/Jk/doc/Jayakrishnan-Resume.docx","@timestamp":"2017-03-17T17:35:46.239Z","@version":"1","host":"Jk","message":["\xBAP\x8A\xA0Ǽy\xF3\xF0\u001C\xD2m\xCE\xFE\xA0N\x9C\x8B\x8BAêiAq0Ѻ0jx\xDB=/\u001F`\\xD3/\\xBAW>\\x90\\xD4J\\x99\\\\*\\xAAބ\\xA2a\\u0012I\\x8F\\x88\\xC5L\\xEC\\xA941q\\xA8\\x9B!fOR\\xC7<b\\\"\\xB3\\xA7\\x91qݶ\\xF7\\x98\\u007F2\\xA0\\x9F1\\xD5\\xD6j\\xC8[\\xBB\\u0002\\xB5\\xFBH\\xFC76z\\u0016\\xB2$\\x84&f^\\xA6\\\\\\xAF\\xB38.\\u0015Nyd\\xD1`\xA3y\xA9q\xF9j4\x95\fx]

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Inspite of mentioning the charset to take in, still the output is not what i expected !
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Logstash cannot read docx files...

Comment: What all file formats can logstash read ??